# How to integrate express-session with ldap js

Tags: node.js, session, express, ldap

I am currently writing a nodejs express application where users can log in, authenticate against an LDAP server and manipulate group membership. For the LDAP api, I am using ldapjs in which I create an ldap client instance which allows me to bind and perform modify operations on existing groups. Now I want to integrate this with express-js routes, so I assume that I need to be able to pass the client object I created into another route. A user logs-in (i.e. successfully binds) and proceeds to a page where he or she can assign users to one group or another (performs modify operations). What is the appropriate strategy for persisting an object from one route to another that is unique for that user's session? Would another approach consist of using express-session middleware to store my user's ldap credentials in a store (say like Redis) and then rebuild my ldapjs client on every route?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of LDAP strategies for [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) ([passport-ldap](https://github.com/mintbridge/passport-ldap) and [passport-ldapauth](https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth)) that may be worth looking into. There doesn't seem to be any other Express session modules for LDAP out there (at least on npm).

Comment: These are authentication modules which can validate a user against an ldap server. Validating a user is one part of my challenge. The other challenge is keeping a persistent bind across multiple routes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "persistent bind" here, but passport supports persistent sessions just like other Express session modules.

Comment: As I understand, to perform any ldap operations, the user must be bound, so consequently, a bind must persist across request and responses. If I need to protect a service with authentication, I could use the passport modules, but in this case I need to perform modify operations on the ldap (ad instance) itself.